# Patternet not converging to a solution

Tags: matlab, neural-network, classification

I need to use a neural network for a binary classifier. I am using Matlab to classify the data, specifically with Patternet. The problem is, the neural network doesn't seem to find a solution. The performance seems to be asymptotic, it doesn't move at all! It's static across the whole training session.

I have had better results with the feedforward net, I get real values as the output and not binary, so I define a threshold (for instance above 0.5 is 1, below 0.5 is zero). Is there a better way to do it?

Why would the feedforward pattern network seems useless for this task but the regular feedforward net for fitting seems a better approach?

Comment: You may need to explain more about the nature of your task and input data before this can be answered. Also, if the question is not about Matlab code, but about applicability of a model class, consider asking in http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ (please read their help section first)

Answer (score -1):

You can try standardizing your data. Non-standardized data tends to have the training algorithm get stuck in local maximum.

You can also increase the hidden layer neurons or even number of hidden layers and try.

Comment: I use mapmaxmin to normalize the data. So it's between -1 and 1. For some reason though, just the regular fitting neural network is giving better results.

Comment: You can increase the hidden layer neurons and try. How many hidden layers are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: I tried with the default settings with 1 hidden layer. I will try increasing the number of hidden layers to see it works better